# Proper way to set up "friends" (bidirectional relationship) in Neo4j.rb

Tags: ruby, neo4j, neo4j.rb

What would be the proper way to create a relationship between `User`s that have a bidirectional relationship?

Say I have:

```
class User
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode

  property :name,   type: String
  property :created_at, type: DateTime
  property :updated_at, type: DateTime

  has_many :both, :friends, model_class: 'User', type: 'connection' unique: true
  has_many :in, :followers, model_class: 'User', type: 'connection', unique: true
  has_many :out, :following, model_class: 'User', type: 'connection', unique: true
end
```

And then,

```
users = [
  User.create(name: 'Foo'),
  User.create(name: 'Bar'),
  User.create(name: 'Baz'),
]
```

Would this be the appropriate way to do it? It seems wildly inefficient:

```
users.each do |user|
  user.friends << users.reject { |u| u == user }
end
```

Comment: I'm confused, why are you iterating over `users` twice?  Also why are you using `<<` to add an array?  I think that's only for individual nodes.  You could build an array and then do something like `user.friends = user_array`

Comment: @BrianUnderwood, that was a poor attempt at ensuring that the user does not have a relationship to themselves. Is there a better way you would suggest accomplishing that?

Comment: Oh, I see, I you're making a relationship between every pair

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to ensure that `user.friends` returns the other two users, I'd actually do this:

```
users.each do |user|
  other_users = users.reject { |u| u == user || user.friends.include?(u) }
  user.friends << other_users
end
```

Now *that* is wildly inefficient! It creates a new array and performs an additional lookup against the database for each user. (FWIW, the `include?` lookup is very fast. You can also remove that `reject` and iterate through `users` once again to speed it up.) Still, it's necessary to accomplish this because otherwise, you'll create duplicate relationships.

Setting `unique: true` in your association is only going to save you in one direction. Queries against `has_many :both` associations use a direction-agnostic Cypher `MATCH` but `CREATE` actions always need direction, so they go from the node on the left to the node on the right. `user1.friends << user2` and `user2.friends << user1` will create two relationships between the two nodes, one in each direction.

**EDIT**

As you pointed out in [your own comment](https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/issues/750#issuecomment-95228791) to an issue on Neo4j.rb, using `user.friends = [other_friends]` will always clear out all existing relationships and prevent duplicates. It's a really cool way of solving the problem.

Comment: Much thanks!

Is there a substantial cost to having duplicate relationships? It seems counterintuitive to create a "follower" relationship when really the logic is such that the user must be "followed" _and_ "following" in order to be "friends".

Comment: That isn't true, though. `user.friends` omits direction: `MATCH (u)-[r:connection]-(other)`. It will match all connections over that relationship type, regardless of direction. Two users will show as "friends" if there is a relationship present.